# Statistics problem

Tags: statistics

let $X$ and $S^2$ be the mean and variance of a random sample size $n=16$ from the normal distribution $N(u, \gamma^2)$

a) find $d$ (using distrubution tables) such that
$P(-d < (X-u)/(S/\sqrt{16}))= 0.95$

b) rewrite the inequalities in part a) so that:
$P[u(X,S) < u < v(X,S)] = 0.95$
Find $u(X,S)$ and $v(X,S)$ so that once $x$ and $s$ are computed the interval $u(x,s)$ to $v(x,s)$ provides a $95\%$ confidence interval for $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#How_the_t-distribution_arises) and use that for both a) and b).